# Google AutoML Vision Exported Model on NVIDIA Jetson Nano

Tags: docker, containers, google-cloud-automl, nvidia-jetson-nano

I would like to run the Exported Model from the Google AutoML Vision on NVIDIA Jetson Nano. Since it is easy I wanted to use the pre-built containers to do predictions following the official [Edge containers tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/containers-gcs-tutorial).

The problem is that the pre-built CPU container stored in Google Container Registry (gcr.io/automl-vision-ondevice/gcloud-container-1.12.0:latest) is based on amd64 arch, while NVIDIA Jetson Nano is using arm64 arch (Ubuntu 18.04). That is why 'docker run ...' returns:

```
docker image error: standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused “exec format error”
```

What can I do? Should I build a container similar to the pre-built one compatible with arm64 arch?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ideas that would help you to achieve your goal:

**[Idea 1]** You could export the model with *.tflite format to do your detection.

**[Idea 2]** Deploy the model as an API service on Google AutoML Vision and call it with python or any other supported language.

Comment: can you explian how to deploy tflite model on jetson nano